# What is the reason to use 결합한 instead of 결합하는 in this case?

Tags: grammar, meaning

敎자는 爻(효 효)자와 子(아들 자)자, 攵(칠 복)자가 결합한 모습이다.

What is the reason to use 결합한 instead of 결합하는 in this case?
The sentence is like a definition so I thought that 결합하는 would be fit with that general thing like that but it's wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at the [definition of -는](https://stdict.korean.go.kr/search/searchView.do?word_no=407005&searchKeywordTo=3) and [-ㄴ](https://stdict.korean.go.kr/search/searchView.do?word_no=57938&searchKeywordTo=3)(boldface added):

> -는: 앞말이 관형어 구실을 하게 하고 이야기하는 시점에서 볼 때 사건이나 행위가 **현재 일어남**을 나타내는 어미.
>
> -ㄴ: 앞말이 관형어 구실을 하게 하고 사건이나 행위가 **과거** 또는 **말하는 이가 상정한 기준 시점보다 과거에 일어남**을 나타내는 어미.

As you see, 敎 is already in its combined form of 爻, 子 and 攵; you don't actively combine them the very moment you use this character. So it would be more appropriate to use -ㄴ here.